# Android TTS for Mandarin Chinese language

Tags: gratis, android, speech-synthesis, language

An Android TTS (Text To Speech) app for Mandarin Chinese language is what I am looking for.

Free, ideally open source.

Your perception of speech quality, and ideally samples of generated speech to evaluate quality, would be appreciated.